# Is there a Ramsey theory for Kneser graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, kneser-graph

Ramsey theory for graphs usually studies colorings of the edges of complete graphs. I'm interested whether there are any results about edge-colorings of Kneser graphs. More specifically, I'm most interested in the following question.

> > If in a two-coloring of $KG(n,k)$ any subKneser graph $KG(3k,k)$ has a red edge, and any triangle has a blue edge, then how large can $n$ be?

Here by subKneser graph $KG(3k,k)$ I mean a subgraph induced by $3k$ of the $n$ elements.
So if the vertices of $KG(n,k)$ are $\binom Sk$ where $|S|=n$, then the vertices of $KG(3k,k)$ should be $\binom {S'}k$ where $S'\subset S$ such that $|S'|=3k$.

The question is related to the three disjoint equivoluminous subsets problem, which is related to the [polymath10](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=The_Erdos-Rado_sunflower_lemma) project.